# How do I hide label if there is text in the box

Tags: html, css, forms

How would I hide 'label' (using css) when there is text in the box.
[[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCvZQ.png) As you can see it still shows the label when there is text in it.

HTML

```
<div class="field-wrap">
    <label>example</label>
    <input type="text" name="example"/>
</div>
<div class="field-wrap">
    <label>example2</label>
    <input type="text" name="example2"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Better if you could create a similar [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net). And how is your `label` inside `text-box`?

Comment: I think you want the 'placeholder' attribute, since youre placing the label inside the input

Answer (score 2):

Use placeholder .

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do it with css only, you need javascript or jquery to do this. Instead of that, use placeholder, as suggested before me.